# class 'MongoClient' not found in php xampp ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, ubuntu, xampp

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I have already looked through the solutions and nothing has worked so far. I am trying to link php with mongodb, and in doing so, these were the steps I followed:

- Installed mongodb driver for php using `sudo pecl install mongo`
- Checked (using phpinfo()), the location of php.ini file (it came out to be in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini).
- Added 'extension=mongo.so', at the end of the file.

This didn't work and I got an error 'Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found...'.

- Next I tried to do it manually. I installed the zip from git, and extracted it. I configured and installed it and found that mongo.so had been created at some file location in usr/lib...
- Checked through `php -i | grep extension_dir`, to look for the location of the extension directory and that came out to be the same as the one where monog.so is located.
- I restarted the apache server, but still am getting the same error.

Besides, there seems to be many php.ini files in my system, like there is one in apache2 folder in etc. I am assuming the correct one is given by phpinfo().

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed MongoDB PHP driver please see this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Update sources

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Install MongoDB PHP Driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear -y
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Open your php.ini file and add to it:

```
extension=mongo.so
```

Restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

***Other helping info:***

this should help to find your php.ini file:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

On Ubuntu it shows this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

take a note, that you run this command from cli (command line) so for your true php.ini go to folder apache2 instead of cli :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link step by step.
http://enginedave.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/install-mongodb-php-driver-to-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

mongoClient has deprecated by in php5.6+
use this instance of :

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```